# Shadow is not taken into account when scrolling

Tags: html, scrollbar, css-position, chromium

In the left part of the following picture you can see an object which has been positioned on the right edge of the container. Part of the object is cut off according to the overflow property and can be displayed by scrolling horizontally to the right.

[image: Object at right border of container, pre and after scrolling to the right]

In the right part of the picture you can see the object after scrolling to the right. The shadow on the right edge of the object is cut off. When scrolling, only the extent (width) of the object without the shadow was taken into account.

[image]

Setting a margin or padding value for the object did not change the behavior. Experiments with the css property scrolling-margin or scrolling-padding have also failed.

The behavior was tested under Chrome (79.0.3945.88), Opera and Edge in the latest versions under Mac OS.

I don't want to create another container around the object to create a space. Is there any other way to avoid cutting off the shadow?

---

The relevant CSS for the container:

```
margin: 4px;
box-sizing: border-box;
overflow: auto;
```

The relevant CSS for the object:

```
background: lightgreen;
background-clip: padding-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: darkslategray;
border-radius: 50%;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px gray;
position: absolute;
```

Comment: Could you supply the HTML?

Comment: I have created an example in Codepen that shows the approximate structure. I enlarged the shadow to make the phenomenon easier to recognize.
https://codepen.io/ekadagami/pen/mdyPybq

Comment: @MrLister - Since it is up to the user where exactly he places the objects in the container, it does not make sense to specify a minimum width. Thanks anyway for the hint.

Comment: @DenisGiffeler That code doesn't seem to be able to replicate the issue, could it be because the boxes are not actually resizable? P.S. Is this Agar.io? lol

Comment: @Laif - I didn't know agar.io until now. Pretty cool. Simply resize the browser window until the left container is too small to hold the circles completely. Or simply change the css "left" attribute of one of the circles to a higher value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this. Put something in the `::after` of the divs and position that slightly to the right.
It sounds like a bit of a kludge, but of all the things I tried, this is the only trick I could get to work.

```css
/* Change line 34 to see the beauty of flex-design ;-) */

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-content: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
}

nav {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: yellow;
  opacity: 0.9;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  user-select: none;
  flex: 0 0 35px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #ddd;
}

main {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  align-self: stretch;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row; /* row, row-reverse, column, column-reverse */
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-content: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
}

article {
  --raster: 25px;
  --raster-color: #ddd;
  margin: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: scroll;
  background-attachment: local;
  background-image: linear-gradient(var(--raster-color) 1px, transparent 1px), linear-gradient(90deg, var(--raster-color) 1px, transparent 1px), linear-gradient(var(--raster-color) 0.5px, transparent 0.5px), linear-gradient(90deg, var(--raster-color) 0.5px, transparent 0.5px);
  background-size: var(--raster) var(--raster), var(--raster) var(--raster), 5px 5px, 5px 5px;
  flex: 3 1 75%;
  align-self: auto;
  position: relative;
}

section {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #ddd;
  flex: 0 0 4px;
  cursor: col-resize;
}

aside {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: lightgray;
  overflow: scroll;
  flex: 1 1 calc(25% + 10px); /* resizing */
  align-self: auto;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 5px;
}

article div {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px gray;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  color: white;
}

/* Trick goes here */
article div::after {
  position: absolute; bottom:-8px; right: -8px;
  display: inline; content: '\00A0';
}

article div:nth-child(1) {
  left: 500px;
  top: 50px;
}

article div:nth-child(2) {
  left: 350px;
  top: 10px;
}

article div:nth-child(3) {
  left: 175px;
  top: 125px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  navigation bar
</nav>
<main>
  <article>
    <div>
      first
    </div>
    <div>
      second
    </div>
    <div>
      third
    </div>
  </article>
  <section></section>
  <aside>
    input area
  </aside>
</main>
```

Comment: It is an interesting proposal. However, since the problem also affects the bottom of the container and scrolling down, this trick doesn't always help, does it?

Comment: @DenisGiffeler Sorry about that; hadn't tested thoroughly enough. How about now?

Comment: That's working. I'll mark this as a solution to the problem, unless someone else notices that the behavior is a general browser implementation error.

Comment: OK. But it's not a browser error! The problem is that the article itself is smaller than the divs within (which are positioned absolutely and don't contribute to the width of the article), and the scrollbars don't care much for invisible decoration such as padding or margin. Or even visible decoration such as shadow or outline. That's why I made my earlier suggestion of making the article larger.